# Controlling The Number Of Items In Multi Line Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am attempting to Write Products to a Multiline Textbox.

I am writing the information like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string output = String.Empty;

    output = String.Format("Cust Name {0}" + Environment.NewLine +
                           "Product Name: {1}" + Environment.NewLine +
                           Customer.Name, Name);
    return output;
}
```

Products are being added one at a time at different times (like a feed).

I want the textbox to only to display the 20 newest Products.

How can I control this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not store the products in a list?

```
List<String> products = new List<String>();


public void addToTextBox(string product)
{
    products.Add(product);

    while(products.Count>20)
    {
         products.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    /* Refresh textbox */

    textBox.Text="";

    foreach(var p in products)
    {
        textBox.AppendText(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: I kinda wanted to show items being added to the textbox one at a time. This will refresh all the data i think?

Comment: This will show the last n items. With only 20 items, the perf hit here is negligible.